# How can I select the right row based on effective date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following (condensed) query to begin :

```
WITH Product_List AS
    (SELECT J.Product_ID,
            N.Product_Name,
            J.Unit_Price,
            J.Effective_Date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY J.Product_ID ORDER BY J.Effective_Date DESC) AS      RowNum
    FROM Company.dbo.Pricing_File AS J
    LEFT JOIN Company.dbo.No_pricing_File AS N ON J.Product_ID = N.Product_ID)
```

The data this pulls will look something like to this:

```
J.Product_ID | N. Product_Name | J.Unit_Price | J.Effective_Date | RowNum
123456       | Product_1       | 12.34        | 01-04-14         | 1
123456       | Product_1       | 12.56        | 01-04-13         | 2
123456       | Product_1       | 12.80        | 01-04-12         | 3
567898       | Product_2       | 10.00        | 01-01-14         | 1
567898       | Product_2       | 9.50         | 01-01-13         | 2
```

I'm now using this list to pull data from for a Product_Name and Unit_price column but the query needs to pull the correct unit_price based off of the effective date. Here is the rest of my query:

```
SELECT 
   A.*,
   B.*,
   Product_List_1.Product_Name,
   Product_List_1.Unit_Price,
FROM 
   Company.dbo.Company_Master AS A
LEFT JOIN Company.dbo.Product_Info AS B ON A.Claim_Number = B.Claim_Number AND A.Customer_Number = B.Customer_Number
LEFT JOIN Product_List AS Product_List_1 ON B.Product_ID_1 = Product_List_1.Product_ID AND
B.Fill_Date >= Product_List_1.Effective_Date AND
Product_List_1.RowNum = 1
```

This works exactly as expected except in one case. When J.Effective_Date is something like 01-04-14 and B.Fill_Date is something like 12-30-13, the criteria I'm joining on is no longer true. Either the effective date is not >= Fill Date OR RowNum != 1. I've tried changing the last line of the JOIN ON from:

```
Product_List_1.RowNum = 1
```

to

```
Product_List_1.RowNum LIKE '[1-2]'
```

and other variations but then it will return more than one result instead of the only one that it should.

My question is, how can I get this query to select the correct record from the Product_List table based on the Fill_Date and Effective_Date?

Thanks for any help. Let me know if you have any questions or need clarification.

Comment: Is your date being stored as a character string?

Comment: No, both Fill_Date and Effective_Date are stored as a datetime data type.

Comment: Could you please build a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3) with enough sample data to demonstrate the edge cases that break your query, and the results you expect... sample data and desired results are often much more effective at getting you the query you need rather than trying to reverse engineering the query you have based on the incorrect results it produces.

Comment: Someone below just got what I needed. In the future, however, I'll certainly consider using SQL Fiddle to articulate my question. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If appears you are trying to get the pricing that applies to a product for a given claim or order based on a list of prices with effective date.  In that case the way I have done it in the past is to join your pricing together so that you get a start/end date instead of just effective date, and join on the start and end date.

Here is an example:

```
;WITH Product_List AS
(SELECT J.Product_ID,
            N.Product_Name,
            J.Unit_Price,
            J.Effective_Date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY J.Product_ID ORDER BY J.Effective_Date DESC) AS      RowNum
    FROM Company.dbo.Pricing_File AS J
    LEFT JOIN Company.dbo.No_pricing_File AS N ON J.Product_ID = N.Product_ID
  )
, ctePriceRange as
(
    SELECT 
        l1.Product_ID, 
        l1.Product_Name,
        l1.Unit_Price,
        l1.Effective_Date as PriceStart,
        l2.Effective_Date as PriceEnd
    FROM Product_List l1
    LEFT JOIN Product_List l2 
    ON l1.Product_ID = l2.Product_ID
    and l1.RowNum = l2.RowNum - 1 --Join this price up with the next available price to get the end date 
)
SELECT 
   A.*,
   B.*,
   Product_List_1.Product_Name,
   Product_List_1.Unit_Price,
FROM 
   Company.dbo.Company_Master AS A
LEFT JOIN Company.dbo.Product_Info AS B ON A.Claim_Number = B.Claim_Number AND A.Customer_Number = B.Customer_Number
LEFT JOIN ctePriceRange AS Product_List_1 ON B.Product_ID_1 = Product_List_1.Product_ID AND
B.Fill_Date >= Product_List_1.PriceStart AND 
(
    B.Fill_Date < Product_List_1.PriceEnd 
    OR 
    Product_List_1.PriceEnd is null --this handles the last effective price that is listed, which will not have an end date
)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you! I will certainly be keeping this sort of set up in mind in the future.